# What are the rules for "w" word motion when characters are not in iskeyword?

Tags: cursor-motions, vi-words

If I have a shell script with code like

```
...
chars+=('5')
chars+=('6')
...
chars+=('%')
chars+=('&')
...
```

and `iskeyword` is defined as

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-
```

This definition indicates to me Vim will consider a continuous sequence of characters from these `iskeywords` characters to be a word.
So if I am here

```
chars+=('5')
 ^ (cursor)
chars+=('6')
```

and press `w`

```
chars+=('5')
     ^ (cursor)
chars+=('6')
```

I end up on `+` which is not the beginning of a word as defined by iskeyword character set. Why? Does Vim stop at the beginning of a group of these non-iskeyword chars because it considers you might be interested in doing something with them?

In this case, wouldn't it be better to say `w` takes you both to the beginning of the next "word" OR the beginning of the next "anti-word" (continuous sequence of characters NOT defined in iskeyword)?

Because code contains a lot of characters not in `iskeyword`, I am interested in knowing the rules for "w" word motion regarding these non-word characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding is that iskeyword doesn't define what a word is; rather, it adjusts where a boundary may happen by adjusting what a keyword is. Both keywords and non-keywords are still "words".

According to `:help word`:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>   tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>   is also considered to be a word.

But, that doesn't quite answer your question exactly.

My understanding is that "iskeyword" is used to group the containing characters as a type of word called "keyword", but that doesn't mean that characters (except whitespace) outside of iskeyword aren't words, but are just non-keywords. Also, it seems that letters and high unicode is considered part of a keyword regardless (from `help 'iskeyword'` and `help 'isfname'`).

As such, when you press <kbd>w</kbd> at the beginning of `chars+=`, the letters are considered part of the same word because they form a keyword, but since `+` and `=` are not in `iskeyword`, that makes them a non-keyword word, which means there is a word separation.

The behavior that I observe is that, outside of whitespace separation, keywords and non-keywords are considered words, and a transition from keyword to non-keyword or from non-keyword to keyword forms a word boundary, just like whitespace forms a word or WORD boundary.

Comment: interesting, I assumed vim uses the term "keyword" in the variable  "iskeyword" (rather than "isword" ) because the iskeyword group serves more purposes than just motions, e.g. completions etc.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Most explanations of the defintion of word/Word seem to imply that distinct **words** must be separated by _something_ between them, be it a whitespace or some special non-word character. But in practice, distinct words can be adjacent to one another without any whitespace or non-words between them. So really the definiton of **word** shold be _A word consists of a sequence of (letters OR digits OR underscores i.e. **keywords**), XOR (a sequence of other non-blank characters i.e. **non-keywords**), separated with white space (spaces, tabs, )_

Answer (score 0):

I get more confused after reading @John O'M 's answer.
But after some search, I get his point.

Here is my notes:

Character classes:

```
\i      identifier character (see 'isident' option)     /\i
\I      like "\i", but excluding digits                 /\I
\k      keyword character (see 'iskeyword' option)      /\k
\K      like "\k", but excluding digits                 /\K

\w      word character:                 [0-9A-Za-z_]    /\w
\W      non-word character:             [^0-9A-Za-z_]   /\W   (ps: not limited to ASCII, can match Chinese charaters)
```

Modified from nvim's help

```
 word/WORD
    I. consist of a sequence of
          group  1.  letters, digits and underscores,  【the definition of `word` can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option. 
                                                           After `set iskeyword+=-`,   `-` becomes a member of group 1
          group  2.  other non-blank characters, (including non-word characters, e.g. Chinese charaters)
                            
                             (when characters in group 1 are seperated by characters in group 2, 
                             such as "I爱you", character "爱" makes the `WORD` become three `word`s.  
                             Similarly, the `WORD` "我n你" contains 3 `word`s
                               
    II. separated with:
                       white space  (spaces,  tabs, <EOL>).
```

I like the use of "XOR" in @Nicholas Cousar's comment:

(modified by me)

> A word consists of a sequence of
> group 1 (letters OR digits OR underscores i.e. keywords),
> XOR
> group 2 (a sequence of other non-blank characters i.e. non-keywords),
> separated with white space (spaces, tabs, )

### Real Example

https://github.com/dominikduda/vim_current_word

pain point:
it solves all the problems other similar plugins have with knowing  what exactly is a word  and  when cursor is on the word.

Plugin determines what is a word based on **what is a keyword in current file type**.
For example `foo#bar` in `.vim` file will be a single word (because vimscript allows to put `#` as part of variable name), but in `.rb` file `foo#bar` will be considered as two words (because `#` starts comment).

> Helps predict how vim word movements (`w`,  `e`,  `b`) will behave

> Plays well with * and #

However, this plugin does not work so well as described !!

This plugin will highlight `I爱U` as a word,  `I-U` will not be highlighted as a word ,because `-` is not in my `iskeyword` (iskeyword=@,48-57,_) .  But nvim' s word motions, e.g., `w` , `*`, and `#`  regard `I爱U` as 3 words.